# Cómo actuar si existe una respuesta borrada y la que se quiere publicar "o se ha publicado" es algo similar

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, respuestas-borradas

Estaba en SOes pero no sé por qué no estaba conectado. Estaba mirando preguntas y encontré esta:

[Poner un char en minúsculas usando C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66845/poner-un-char-en-min%C3%BAsculas-usando-c)

y me dije ha pero también se puede hacer de la manera que [publiqué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67065/83). El caso es que fui a Ideone e hice un codigo para que lo pudiera ver. Al intentar contestar me dice que tengo que hacer login y nada, pero cuando se conecta y empiezo a editar la respuesta tras navegar hacia la pregunta, veo que existe una respuesta eliminada, que decía algo así:

> Lo podes asignar a un int, por lo que quedaría guardado el numero
>   ASCii, y luego le restas 32 (fijate bien en la tabla ASCii, pero creo
>   que esa es la diferencia).

¿Cómo actuar en este caso? Yo publiqué mi respuesta por varios motivos:

- El primero es que ya la tenía casi redactada, si a redactar se llama a lo que yo hago.
- Lo segundo, que esa respuesta estaba publicada hace bastantes horas e imagino que si el usuario hubiera querido extenderla contó con algunas horas para ello, (aunque nunca se sabe, si tenía tiempo o no)
- Y tercero, aunque la idea puede ser la "misma" es muy confusa como respuesta.

Todo este rollo es para saber ustedes qué opinan, y si debería haber esperado, o para publicar la respuesta, o tener alguna otra cosa en cuenta.

Comment: Yo recomiendo que publiques tu respuesta.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias por contestar edicion ect, en una respuesta de abajo hace un comentario que esta relacionano con otro en este hilo, algo asi *...si se toman ideas de ella creo pertinente indicarlo con una mención del algún tipo...* Aunque realmente no tome la idea de esa "respuesta" pues ya lo sabia y ni siquiera lo habia visto cuando la esta escribiendo, si es cierto que pense en poner alguna mencion, pero al leer "...pero creo que esa es la diferencia..." se me quitaron las "ganas" por decirlo de alguna manera. Saludos

Answer (score 5):

En la pregunta en concreto de la que hablas, la respuesta eliminada tiene un comentario mio con 3 votos de apoyo, indicando que **no es una respuesta de calidad**, y que **mas parece un comentario**, ademas de otro comentario adicional indicando que **no provee una respuesta a la pregunta** y que podrá comentar cuando tenga suficiente reputación.

Aunque esa respuesta **no hubiera sido eliminada**, difícilmente podría calificarse de *respuesta*: 2 líneas (**literalmente, 2 líneas**), con una idea vaga, y sin aportar siquiera datos concretos; copio/pego:

> Lo podes asignar a un int, por lo que quedaría guardado el numero ASCii, y luego le restas 32 (fijate bien en la tabla ASCii, pero creo que esa es la diferencia).

En resumen: aunque **no** se hubiera eliminado, **a mi juicio personal**, tu respuesta es **mucho** mas respuesta, con datos concretos y una explicación detallada. Merece ser publicada (y votada), aunque la otra hubiera permanecido expuesta.

Comment: Gracias contestar y dar su punto de vista, despues de publicar lei los comentario y recuerdo el suyo, pues fui a dar upvote pero no pude por estar eliminada o algo asi, sobre la linea que recalca en su respuesta *(fijate bien en la tabla ASCii, pero creo que esa es la diferencia)* fue la que determino que no lo mencionara en la respuesta mia, aunque no saque la idea de esa respuesta pues no la habia visto si que pense en mencionarlo hasta leer bien su respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Según he leído la pregunta iba decidido a poner una respuesta pero es que esta plasma perfectamente lo que pienso al respecto

Answer (score 2):

Por una lado, si una publicación está borrada, debe considerarse como tal, en otras palabras, actuar como si no existiera, por otro lado Para poder acceder a las publicaciones borradas se requiere del privilegio de acceso a herramientas de moderador (rep>= 2000), así que esto refuerza la sugerencia de actuar como si no existiera, más específicamente, si no lo has hecho aún, **publica tu respuesta** y si ya lo hiciste, si *procura que tu respuesta se distinga de la otra*, ya sea porque incluyes información relevante no incluida en la otra, incluyes una explicación dada de forma diferente la cual podría ser más clara para algunos, etc.

Como el nombre del privilegio citado lo indica, el acceso a las publicaciones eliminadas es para fines de moderación, entiéndase resolver situaciones que requieren de cierto criterio y credibilidad.

Comment: A mi parecer, el estado borrado de una publicación no deja de ser transitorio (aunque en la mayoría de casos definitivo). Por ello, si se toman ideas de ella creo pertinente indicarlo con una mención del algún tipo.